# Display current value of PHP variable in realtime using js/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

This might seem easy enough for the lovely experts here at SO :) but I can't find a decent answer/question about this on SO or google. Pls help. :)

How do i display a current value of a php variable in realtime via AJAX/js/jQuery

Basically im trying to do an E-commerce site and I am storing the shopping cart contents using a session and displaying it with an echo statement counting how many contents is currently in the basket, however when they are on a certain product and tried adding it in the cart, the value of the cart doesn't echo the added item until there is a page refresh, so i need something like an AJAX to display the updated value of the session when an item is added without having a page refresh.

Thank you so much.

Here is my code snippet for the cart as a sample:

```
// Assign shopping cart ($_SESSION['cart']) into variable
$basket = count($_SESSION['cart']);
```

And for displaying:

```
<!-- Display contents of the shopping cart -->
<ul id="basket" class="clearfix">
   <li class="top">
      <a href="checkout.php" class="top_link"> 
         <span>Items: <? echo $basket ?></span>
      </a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you so much.. kindly provide a sample code on how to achieve this (either js or jQuery) and would help as well for best practices in dealing with this type of scenario.

Comment: a little ajax research would find the answer

Comment: @Dagon I've been looking at a lot of questions on this in ajax but most of the codes provided are mostly based on a difrnt scenario or in deeper implementations. a little research on AJAX on this should have been able to provide a link for me and i wouldnt be needing to ask this if i can easily find it. AJAX is a very vague topic that has many implementations even just typing 'how to display a php variable on realtime' on google will give u many types of results that are complex. Providing a link or helping would have been much appreciated for someone who is just starting to learn programming.

Comment: At the most basic level, create a new PHP file.  Make an AJAX call to this new PHP file.  JQuery makes it easy to make AJAX requests.  The PHP file would echo the contents of your $_SESSION.  The AJAX callback handler(s) can then receive this data as an argument and you can do whatever you want with it at that point.

Answer (score 0):

***First solution (based on your request - BAD IDEA)***

```
get-count-items.php
<?php
    session_start();
    die(count($_SESSION['cart']));
?>

Javascript
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.post('get-count-items.php', {}, function (total_items){
            $('#total-items').html(total_items);
        });
    }, '1000');
</script>

HTML
<ul id="basket" class="clearfix">
    <li class="top">
        <a href="checkout.php" class="top_link"> 
            <span>Items: <span id="total-items"><? echo $basket ?></span></span>
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

This javascript will make a request to server at each 1 second.

***Second solution (event on button "Add to cart")***

```
add-to-cart.php
<?php
    session_start();
            // code for add to cart...
    die(count($_SESSION['cart']));
?>


Javascript
<script>
    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
        $.post('add-to-cart.php', {}, function (total_items){
            $('#total-items').html(items);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

HTML
<ul id="basket" class="clearfix">
    <li class="top">
        <a href="checkout.php" class="top_link"> 
            <span>Items: <span id="total-items"><? echo $basket ?></span></span>
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="" class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</>
```

Comment: thank you so much.. i will try this now :) , btw, would this have any effect in terms of the server processes if there are more users using the system say 20-30 users concurrently, so its like 30 browsers requesting every 1 second to the server at the same time. would it be possible to have an event based function that only makes the request/call on the values of the variable/session when they click the add to cart button? thanks. :)

Comment: @GitKidd yes. this is a problem. just added second solution.